# music21 : given midi input, output correctly-spelled pitches with octave numbers

Tags: python, music21

**See Edit below for a work-in-progress MRE**

I'm trying to transform the `text` output of music21 to include octave numbers and correct enharmonic spelling.

As background, I'm a javascript programmer, new to music21 and python.

The following

```
myMusic = converter.parse("midi")
myMusic.show("text")
```

yields

```
Time      Actual output      Desired Output 
{0.0} <music21.note.Note C>      C4
{0.1} <music21.note.Note D#>     E-4
{0.2} <music21.note.Note G>      G4
{0.3} <music21.note.Note G>      G4
```

Where there are two issues:

1. How do I include the octave in the text output?  (Interestingly, when there are chords, the octave of each note does appear.
2. The `D#` should be an `Eb`, i.e., should be interpreted in a tonal context.  I'd like to run `EnharmonicSimplifier.bestPitches()` on the whole parsed midi file to correct this, but [from the docs](https://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/moduleReference/moduleAnalysisEnharmonics.html), it appears that it can only be run on a `note list`.

Am I going about this wrong?  Should I be outputting to a different format to get this info?  I need timepoints (offset is ok), octave numbers, and correctly-spelled pitches.  Maybe I'm missing intermediate processing?

Any guidance appreciated.

**EDIT: Work in progress MRE, solves issue 1. (badly?), but not 2.**

```
from music21 import *
environment.set('autoDownload', 'allow')

stream1 = converter.parse("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/MIDI_sample.mid")

for n in stream1.recurse().notes:
  try: 
    print(n.offset, n.nameWithOctave)
  except Exception as e: 
    print(n.offset, *n.pitches)
```

Yields (excerpted)

```
237.5 C2
238.0 F#2
238.2 F#2
238.5 C2 F#2
238.7 B-2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1

`.show()` is nice at a glance when debugging but not ideal for structured output. Have a look at `recurse()`. music21 has a container ontology: objects are "in" voices, "in" measures, "in" parts, "in" scores. So if you start top-down from a score and want to walk every nested container, just use recurse():

```
for n in myStream.recurse().notes:
   print(n.offset, ' '.join(p.nameWithOctave for p in n.pitches))
```

Note properties: http://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/moduleReference/moduleNote.html

2

`simplifyMultipleEnharmonics()` takes an iterable of pitches (or things that can be converted to pitches, but faster to give it the pitches if you've got 'em). Every Note or Chord object has a `pitches` attribute, so you can safely call `.pitches` on Notes or Chords while looping through your parsed file and send that tuple of pitches to `simplifyMultipleEnharmonics`, along with your Key object.

```
for n in myStream.recurse().notes:
  closest_key = n.getContextByClass(key.Key)
  n.pitches = pitch.simplifyMultipleEnharmonics(n.pitches, keyContext=closest_key)
```

Comment: The text explanation gives me a high-level understanding -- thanks! -- but I'm having implementation issues. (**Bold** for clarity, not shouting)  **Re: 1.**, `nameWithOctave` fails for chords.  I added `except Try ... Exception as e:  print(n.offset, *n.pitches)`, which solves that, but probably isn't the best way.  **Re: 2.** Attempted, but too abstract given my first contact with Python.  Could your answer **include a code sample that actually produces the desired output for a .mid file?**  Here's a sample from wikipedia: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/MIDI_sample.mid

Comment: Yes, good call, nameWithOctave only makes sense on a single object, so my example now prints a list of names. And a code example for #2.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error for 1.  Will check 2. when I get a chance, but makes sense!

Comment: Edited, sorry!!

Comment: That makes sense now!  If you're a developer for music21, it might be worth considering including an example like this in the docs, since I'd imagine pitches with time points is a pretty common use-case.  In any case, I appreciate the help!